# Trying to put together a teaching-example with pyhf

Tags: pyhf

I'm trying to learn more about pyhf and my understanding of what the goals are might be limited. I would love to fit my HEP data outside of ROOT, but I could be imposing expectations on pyhf which are not what the authors intended for it's use.

I'd like to write myself a hello-world example, but I might just not know what I'm doing. My misunderstanding could also be gaps in my statistical knowledge.

With that preface, let me explain what I'm trying to explore.

I have some observed set of events for which I calculate some observable and make a binned histogram of that data. I hypothesize that there are two contributing physics processes, which I call signal and background. I generate some Monte Carlo samples for these processes and the theorized total number of events is close to, but not exactly what I observe.

I would like to:

- Fit the data to this two process hypothesis
- Get from the fit the optimal values for the number of events for each process
- Get the uncertainties on these fitted values
- If appropriate, calculate an upper limit on the number of signal events.

My starter code is below, where all I'm doing is an ML fit but I'm not sure where to go. I know it's not set up to do what I want, but I'm getting lost in the examples I find on RTD. I'm sure it's me, this is not a criticism of the documentation.

```py
import pyhf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nbins = 15

# Generate a background and signal MC sample`
MC_signal_events = np.random.normal(5,1.0,200)
MC_background_events = 10*np.random.random(1000)

signal_data = np.histogram(MC_signal_events,bins=nbins)[0]
bkg_data = np.histogram(MC_background_events,bins=nbins)[0]

# Generate an observed dataset with a slightly different
# number of events
signal_events = np.random.normal(5,1.0,180)
background_events = 10*np.random.random(1050)

observed_events = np.array(signal_events.tolist() + background_events.tolist())
observed_sample = np.histogram(observed_events,bins=nbins)[0]


# Plot these samples, if you like
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.hist(observed_events,bins=nbins,label='Observations')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.hist(MC_signal_events,bins=nbins,label='MC signal')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.hist(MC_background_events,bins=nbins,label='MC background')
plt.legend()

# Use a very naive estimate of the background
# uncertainties
bkg_uncerts = np.sqrt(bkg_data)

print("Defining the PDF.......")
pdf = pyhf.simplemodels.hepdata_like(signal_data=signal_data.tolist(), \
                                     bkg_data=bkg_data.tolist(), \
                                     bkg_uncerts=bkg_uncerts.tolist())

print("Fit.......")
data = pyhf.tensorlib.astensor(observed_sample.tolist() + pdf.config.auxdata)

bestfit_pars, twice_nll = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, pdf, return_fitted_val=True)

print(bestfit_pars)
print(twice_nll)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this answer is based on pyhf v0.5.2.*

Alright, so it looks like you've managed to figure most of the big pieces for sure. However, there's two different ways to do this depending on how you prefer to set things up. In both cases, I assume you want an unconstrained fit and you want to...

1. fit your signal+background model to observed data
2. fit your background model to observed data

First, let's discuss uncertainties briefly. At the moment, we default to `numpy` for the tensor background and `scipy` for the optimizer. See documentation:

- [numpy backend](https://scikit-hep.org/pyhf/_generated/pyhf.tensor.numpy_backend.numpy_backend.html#pyhf.tensor.numpy_backend.numpy_backend)
- [scipy optimizer](https://scikit-hep.org/pyhf/_generated/pyhf.optimize.opt_scipy.scipy_optimizer.html#pyhf.optimize.opt_scipy.scipy_optimizer)

However, one unfortunate drawback right now with the `scipy` optimizer is that it cannot return the uncertainties. What you need to do anywhere in your code before the fit (although we generally recommend as early as possible) is to use the `minuit` optimizer instead:

```
pyhf.set_backend('numpy', 'minuit')
```

This will get you the nice features of being able to get the correlation matrix, the uncertainties on the fitted parameters, and the hessian -- amongst other things. We're working to make this consistent for scipy as well, but this is not ready right now.

All optimizations go through our `optimizer` API which you can currently view through the [mixin here](https://scikit-hep.org/pyhf/_generated/pyhf.optimize.mixins.OptimizerMixin.html#pyhf.optimize.mixins.OptimizerMixin.minimize) in our documentation. Specifically, the signature is

```
minimize(
    objective, 
    data, 
    pdf, 
    init_pars, 
    par_bounds, 
    fixed_vals=None, 
    return_fitted_val=False, 
    return_result_obj=False, 
    do_grad=None, 
    do_stitch=False, 
    **kwargs)
```

There are a lot of options here. Let's just focus on the fact that one of the keyword arguments we can pass through is `return_uncertainties` which will change the bestfit parameters by adding a column for the fitted parameter uncertainty which you want.

---

### 1. Signal+Background

In this case, we want to just use the default model

```
result, twice_nll = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(
    data,
    pdf,
    return_uncertainties=True,
    return_fitted_val=True
)

bestfit_pars, errors = result.T
```

### 2. Background-Only

In this case, we need to turn off the signal. The way we do this is by setting the parameter of interest (POI) fixed to 0.0. Then we can get the fitted parameters for the background-only model in a similar way, but using `fixed_poi_fit` instead of an unconstrained fit:

```
result, twice_nll = pyhf.infer.mle.fixed_poi_fit(
    0.0,
    data,
    pdf,
    return_uncertainties=True,
    return_fitted_val=True
)

bestfit_pars, errors = result.T
```

Note that this is quite simply a quick way of doing the following unconstrained fit

```
bkg_params = pdf.config.suggested_init()
fixed_params = pdf.config.suggested_fixed()

bkg_params[pdf.config.poi_index] = 0.0
fixed_params[pdf.config.poi_index] = True

result, twice_nll = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(
    data,
    pdf,
    init_pars=bkg_params,
    fixed_params=fixed_params,
    return_uncertainties=True,
    return_fitted_val=True
)

bestfit_pars, errors = result.T
```

---

Hopefully that clarifies things up more!

Comment: Thanks, @kratsg! I'm going to try this out but the first thing I get when trying to use `minuit` is an error. I don't see on the pyhf site how to properly install it. Should I be using `iminuit` or the older `pyminuit`?

Comment: OK, I installed `iminuit`. But should that first line be

`pyhf.set_backend('numpy', 'minuit')`


I get an error if the first argument is `scipy`

Comment: It's working! Thanks! OK, off to play with this. When i clean it up I'll post it back here.

Comment: You're right, sorry - I've edited it to be `numpy` and not `scipy`. Sorry for the mistake. To get minuit, you can do `pip install pyhf[minuit]`.

Comment: Ok, if this answers your question, you should feel free to mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Giordon's solution should answer all of your question, but I thought I'd also write out the code to basically address everything we can.
I also take the liberty of changing some of your values a bit so that the signal isn't so strong that the observed CLs value isn't far off to the right of the Brazil band (the results aren't wrong obviously, but it probably makes more sense to be talking about using the discovery test statistic at that point then setting limits. :))

## Environment

For this example I'm going to setup a clean Python 3 virtual environment and then install the dependencies (here we're going to be using `pyhf` `v0.5.2`)

```
$ python3 -m venv "${HOME}/.venvs/question"
$ . "${HOME}/.venvs/question/bin/activate"
(question) $ cat requirements.txt
pyhf[minuit,contrib]~=0.5.2
black
(question) $ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## Code

While we can't easily get the best fit value for both the number of signal events as well as the background events we definitely can do inference to get the best fit value for the signal strength.
The following chunk of code (which is long only because of the visualization) should address all of the points of your question.

```py
# answer.py
import numpy as np
import pyhf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyhf.contrib.viz.brazil

# Goals:
#    - Fit the model to the observed data
#    - Infer the best fit signal strength given the model
#    - Get the uncertainties on the best fit signal strength
#    - Calculate an 95% CL upper limit on the signal strength


def plot_hist(ax, bins, data, bottom=0, color=None, label=None):
    bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
    bin_leftedges = bins[:-1]
    bin_centers = [edge + bin_width / 2.0 for edge in bin_leftedges]
    ax.bar(
        bin_centers, data, bin_width, bottom=bottom, alpha=0.5, color=color, label=label
    )


def plot_data(ax, bins, data, label="Data"):
    bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
    bin_leftedges = bins[:-1]
    bin_centers = [edge + bin_width / 2.0 for edge in bin_leftedges]
    ax.scatter(bin_centers, data, color="black", label=label)


def invert_interval(test_mus, hypo_tests, test_size=0.05):
    # This will be taken care of in v0.5.3
    cls_obs = np.array([test[0] for test in hypo_tests]).flatten()
    cls_exp = [
        np.array([test[1][idx] for test in hypo_tests]).flatten() for idx in range(5)
    ]
    crossing_test_stats = {"exp": [], "obs": None}
    for cls_exp_sigma in cls_exp:
        crossing_test_stats["exp"].append(
            np.interp(
                test_size, list(reversed(cls_exp_sigma)), list(reversed(test_mus))
            )
        )
    crossing_test_stats["obs"] = np.interp(
        test_size, list(reversed(cls_obs)), list(reversed(test_mus))
    )
    return crossing_test_stats


def main():
    np.random.seed(0)
    pyhf.set_backend("numpy", "minuit")

    observable_range = [0.0, 10.0]
    bin_width = 0.5
    _bins = np.arange(observable_range[0], observable_range[1] + bin_width, bin_width)

    n_bkg = 2000
    n_signal = int(np.sqrt(n_bkg))

    # Generate simulation
    bkg_simulation = 10 * np.random.random(n_bkg)
    signal_simulation = np.random.normal(5, 1.0, n_signal)

    bkg_sample, _ = np.histogram(bkg_simulation, bins=_bins)
    signal_sample, _ = np.histogram(signal_simulation, bins=_bins)

    # Generate observations
    signal_events = np.random.normal(5, 1.0, int(n_signal * 0.8))
    bkg_events = 10 * np.random.random(int(n_bkg + np.sqrt(n_bkg)))

    observed_events = np.array(signal_events.tolist() + bkg_events.tolist())
    observed_sample, _ = np.histogram(observed_events, bins=_bins)

    # Visualize the simulation and observations
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)

    plot_hist(ax, _bins, bkg_sample, label="Background")
    plot_hist(ax, _bins, signal_sample, bottom=bkg_sample, label="Signal")
    plot_data(ax, _bins, observed_sample)
    ax.legend(loc="best")
    ax.set_ylim(top=np.max(observed_sample) * 1.4)
    ax.set_xlabel("Observable")
    ax.set_ylabel("Count")
    fig.savefig("components.png")

    # Build the model
    bkg_uncerts = np.sqrt(bkg_sample)
    model = pyhf.simplemodels.hepdata_like(
        signal_data=signal_sample.tolist(),
        bkg_data=bkg_sample.tolist(),
        bkg_uncerts=bkg_uncerts.tolist(),
    )
    data = pyhf.tensorlib.astensor(observed_sample.tolist() + model.config.auxdata)

    # Perform inference
    fit_result = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, model, return_uncertainties=True)
    bestfit_pars, par_uncerts = fit_result.T
    print(
        f"best fit parameters:\
        \n * signal strength: {bestfit_pars[0]} +/- {par_uncerts[0]}\
        \n * nuisance parameters: {bestfit_pars[1:]}\
        \n * nuisance parameter uncertainties: {par_uncerts[1:]}"
    )

    # Perform hypothesis test scan
    _start = 0.0
    _stop = 5
    _step = 0.1
    poi_tests = np.arange(_start, _stop + _step, _step)

    print("\nPerforming hypothesis tests\n")
    hypo_tests = [
        pyhf.infer.hypotest(
            mu_test,
            data,
            model,
            return_expected_set=True,
            return_test_statistics=True,
            qtilde=True,
        )
        for mu_test in poi_tests
    ]

    # Upper limits on signal strength
    results = invert_interval(poi_tests, hypo_tests)

    print(f"Observed Limit on µ: {results['obs']:.2f}")
    print("-----")
    for idx, n_sigma in enumerate(np.arange(-2, 3)):
        print(
            "Expected {}Limit on µ: {:.3f}".format(
                "       " if n_sigma == 0 else "({} σ) ".format(n_sigma),
                results["exp"][idx],
            )
        )

    # Visualize the "Brazil band"
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)

    ax.set_title("Hypothesis Tests")
    ax.set_ylabel(r"$\mathrm{CL}_{s}$")
    ax.set_xlabel(r"$\mu$")

    pyhf.contrib.viz.brazil.plot_results(ax, poi_tests, hypo_tests)
    fig.savefig("brazil_band.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which when run gives

```
(question) $ python answer.py
best fit parameters:        
 * signal strength: 1.5884737977889158 +/- 0.7803435235862329        
 * nuisance parameters: [0.99020988 1.06040191 0.90488207 1.03531383 1.09093327 1.00942088
 1.07789316 1.01125627 1.06202964 0.95780043 0.94990993 1.04893286
 1.0560711  0.9758487  0.93692481 1.04683181 1.05785515 0.92381263
 0.93812855 0.96751869]        
 * nuisance parameter uncertainties: [0.06966439 0.07632218 0.0611428  0.07230328 0.07872258 0.06899675
 0.07472849 0.07403246 0.07613661 0.08606657 0.08002775 0.08655314
 0.07564512 0.07308117 0.06743479 0.07383134 0.07460864 0.06632003
 0.06683251 0.06270965]

Performing hypothesis tests

/home/stackoverflow/.venvs/question/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhf/infer/calculators.py:229: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  teststat = (qmu - qmu_A) / (2 * self.sqrtqmuA_v)
Observed Limit on µ: 2.89
-----
Expected (-2 σ) Limit on µ: 0.829
Expected (-1 σ) Limit on µ: 1.110
Expected        Limit on µ: 1.542
Expected (1 σ) Limit on µ: 2.147
Expected (2 σ) Limit on µ: 2.882
```

[image: components.png]

[image: brazil_band.png]

Let us know if you have any further questions!