# Using `pyhf` to float both signal and background strength

Tags: statistics, pyhf

Hi pyhf users and developers!

I have a question that follows from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257667/trying-to-put-together-a-teaching-example-with-pyhf) and so I'll start with the `anwser.py` code provided in one of the responses and thena minor modification.

So I run the fit with the parameters given in the response but I then want to see the results of the fit, so I add some code to weight the original templates by the fit results and replot it with the overlays. The full script is below.

```py
import pyhf
import pyhf.contrib.viz.brazil

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


#    - Get the uncertainties on the best fit signal strength
#    - Calculate an 95% CL upper limit on the signal strength

tag = "ORIGINAL"


def plot_hist(ax, bins, data, bottom=0, color=None, label=None):
    bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
    bin_leftedges = bins[:-1]
    bin_centers = [edge + bin_width / 2.0 for edge in bin_leftedges]
    ax.bar(
        bin_centers, data, bin_width, bottom=bottom, alpha=0.5, color=color, label=label
    )


def plot_data(ax, bins, data, label="Data"):
    bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
    bin_leftedges = bins[:-1]
    bin_centers = [edge + bin_width / 2.0 for edge in bin_leftedges]
    ax.scatter(bin_centers, data, color="black", label=label)


def invert_interval(test_mus, hypo_tests, test_size=0.05):
    # This will be taken care of in v0.5.3
    cls_obs = np.array([test[0] for test in hypo_tests]).flatten()
    cls_exp = [
        np.array([test[1][idx] for test in hypo_tests]).flatten() for idx in range(5)
    ]
    crossing_test_stats = {"exp": [], "obs": None}
    for cls_exp_sigma in cls_exp:
        crossing_test_stats["exp"].append(
            np.interp(
                test_size, list(reversed(cls_exp_sigma)), list(reversed(test_mus))
            )
        )
    crossing_test_stats["obs"] = np.interp(
        test_size, list(reversed(cls_obs)), list(reversed(test_mus))
    )
    return crossing_test_stats


def main():
    np.random.seed(0)
    pyhf.set_backend("numpy", "minuit")

    observable_range = [0.0, 10.0]
    bin_width = 0.5
    _bins = np.arange(observable_range[0], observable_range[1] + bin_width, bin_width)

    n_bkg = 2000
    n_signal = int(np.sqrt(n_bkg))

    # Generate simulation
    bkg_simulation = 10 * np.random.random(n_bkg)
    signal_simulation = np.random.normal(5, 1.0, n_signal)

    bkg_sample, _ = np.histogram(bkg_simulation, bins=_bins)
    signal_sample, _ = np.histogram(signal_simulation, bins=_bins)

    # Generate observations
    signal_events = np.random.normal(5, 1.0, int(n_signal * 0.8))
    bkg_events = 10 * np.random.random(int(n_bkg + np.sqrt(n_bkg)))

    observed_events = np.array(signal_events.tolist() + bkg_events.tolist())
    observed_sample, _ = np.histogram(observed_events, bins=_bins)

    # Visualize the simulation and observations
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)

    plot_hist(ax, _bins, bkg_sample, label="Background")
    plot_hist(ax, _bins, signal_sample, bottom=bkg_sample, label="Signal")
    plot_data(ax, _bins, observed_sample)
    ax.legend(loc="best")
    ax.set_ylim(top=np.max(observed_sample) * 1.4)
    ax.set_xlabel("Observable")
    ax.set_ylabel("Count")
    fig.savefig("components_{0}.png".format(tag))

    # Build the model
    bkg_uncerts = np.sqrt(bkg_sample)
    model = pyhf.simplemodels.hepdata_like(
        signal_data=signal_sample.tolist(),
        bkg_data=bkg_sample.tolist(),
        bkg_uncerts=bkg_uncerts.tolist(),
    )
    data = pyhf.tensorlib.astensor(observed_sample.tolist() + model.config.auxdata)

    # Perform inference
    fit_result = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, model, return_uncertainties=True)
    bestfit_pars, par_uncerts = fit_result.T
    print(
        f"best fit parameters:\
        \n * signal strength: {bestfit_pars[0]} +/- {par_uncerts[0]}\
        \n * nuisance parameters: {bestfit_pars[1:]}\
        \n * nuisance parameter uncertainties: {par_uncerts[1:]}"
    )

    # Visualize the results
    fit_bkg_sample = []
    for w,b in zip(bestfit_pars[1:],bkg_sample):
        fit_bkg_sample.append(w*b)

    fit_signal_sample = bestfit_pars[0]*np.array(signal_sample)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)

    plot_hist(ax, _bins, fit_bkg_sample, label="Background")
    plot_hist(ax, _bins, fit_signal_sample, bottom=fit_bkg_sample, label="Signal")
    plot_data(ax, _bins, observed_sample)
    ax.legend(loc="best")
    ax.set_ylim(top=np.max(observed_sample) * 1.4)
    ax.set_xlabel("Observable")
    ax.set_ylabel("Count")
    fig.savefig("components_after_fit_{0}.png".format(tag))


    # Perform hypothesis test scan
    _start = 0.0
    _stop = 5
    _step = 0.1
    poi_tests = np.arange(_start, _stop + _step, _step)

    print("\nPerforming hypothesis tests\n")
    hypo_tests = [
        pyhf.infer.hypotest(
            mu_test,
            data,
            model,
            return_expected_set=True,
            return_test_statistics=True,
            qtilde=True,
        )
        for mu_test in poi_tests
    ]

    # Upper limits on signal strength
    results = invert_interval(poi_tests, hypo_tests)

    print(f"Observed Limit on µ: {results['obs']:.2f}")
    print("-----")
    for idx, n_sigma in enumerate(np.arange(-2, 3)):
        print(
            "Expected {}Limit on µ: {:.3f}".format(
                "       " if n_sigma == 0 else "({} σ) ".format(n_sigma),
                results["exp"][idx],
            )
        )

    # Visualize the "Brazil band"
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)

    ax.set_title("Hypothesis Tests")
    ax.set_ylabel(r"$\mathrm{CL}_{s}$")
    ax.set_xlabel(r"$\mu$")

    pyhf.contrib.viz.brazil.plot_results(ax, poi_tests, hypo_tests)
    fig.savefig("brazil_band_{0}.png".format(tag))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run it, I get the following plots. The first is original observations/simulation and the second plot has the simulation scaled by the fit results.

[image: Original components and observations]

[image: Components and observations after fit]

So this all looks good and I think I understand what his happening.

But now I ask a question, which is better illustrated with a slight variation on your example.

I'm going to modify the generated simulations and observations such that there are a different number of background events in the simulations and samples. I'm also making the signal more significant. This would be an example where I've not been able to get a good estimation of the background contribution(s) prior to doing the fit. In the example you provide, the number of background events is the same for the simulated sample and data, which is not going to be the case in the real world.

So I go to the above code and I change these lines.

```py
    n_bkg = 2000
    n_signal = 200

    # Generate simulation
    bkg_simulation = 10 * np.random.random(n_bkg)
    signal_simulation = np.random.normal(5, 1.0, n_signal)

    bkg_sample, _ = np.histogram(bkg_simulation, bins=_bins)
    signal_sample, _ = np.histogram(signal_simulation, bins=_bins)

    # Generate observations
    signal_events = np.random.normal(5, 1.0, int(n_signal * 0.8))
    bkg_events = 10 * np.random.random(n_bkg - 300)
```

The fit isn't great, and I wouldn't expect it to be since I locked down the number of background events, modulo the Poisson fluctuations in each bin. The relevant plots (before/after fit) are shown here.

[image: Original components and observations for modified values]

[image: Components and observations after fit for modified values]

I might have thought another way to approach this would be to add another non-nuisance, floating parameter that represents the background strength, while still letting the individual bins vary within Poisson fluctuations. For that matter, couldn't (shouldn't?) the signal bins fluctuate as well?

In that case, I would then start with my a vastly larger number of data points in my simulated samples to get the more "true" (I know that's not rigorous) distribution. Once the fit drives the number of signal/background events down, Poisson fluctuations would become more significant.

I'm sure the optimization/minimization of the likelihood function becomes much more difficult but it also feels like we're constraining the fit too early if we lock down the bulk background normalization. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks as always for your help and response!

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to add a new nuisance by adding a "normfactor" modifier to the background component

e.g.

```
spec = {'channels': [{'name': 'singlechannel',
   'samples': [{'name': 'signal',
     'data': [10.0],
     'modifiers': [{'name': 'mu', 'type': 'normfactor', 'data': None}]},
    {'name': 'background',
     'data': [50.0],
     'modifiers': [{'name': 'bkgnorm',
       'type': 'normfactor',
       'data': None}]}]}]}
```

see the symmetry between signal and background

Comment: I don't see how to incorporate this into the example I provided. If your answer referencing a different example?

Comment: Hi @mattbellis - apologies for the terse answer, I was in a rush.  the `pyhf.simplemodels.hepdata_like` is only a convenience function to create a pyhf JSON spec (see what it actually does here: https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/blob/master/src/pyhf/simplemodels.py ). if you want to add more nuisance parameters you nneed to create a JSON spec yourself and the above should work.

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I see. 

Your example works for me, but the JSON validator fails when I include a term for the background uncertainty, even though the source code you link to says it should be OK.

So if I change that last "None" to be [7.0], it fails.

Comment: That next-to-last line has to be '"type": "shapesys", not 'normfactor' if it is to pass the JSON validator. But I don't think that's what I want.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. I need two modifiers for the background: one is a 'normfactor' and one is a 'shapefactor' with the individual uncertainties on the bins.